# Delete records from Cassandra table based on their unavailability in another Cassandra table using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two Cassandra Tables

Table-1 `[tb1_id, tb2_id, first_req_time, other_fields, Primary Key(tb1_id)]`

Table-2 `[tb2_id, other_fields, Primary Key(tb2_id)]`

Both the tables are huge(around 300 GB each), Table-1 has around 2.5 billion records, Table-2 has 220 million records.

now, I want to regularly delete some records from Table-1(to maintain size) based on these criteria:-

1. if first_req_time is older than 6 months.
2. for a record [tb1_id, tb2_id] in table-1, there is no corresponding record in table-2.

```
import java.util.Calendar
import com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.{Delete, QueryBuilder, Select}
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import java.util.ArrayList
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
import java.util.UUID.randomUUID

def isRecordActive(row: com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow, refTime: Long): Boolean = {
  val first_req_time = row.get[Option[Long]]("first_req_time").getOrElse(0L)
  first_req_time >= refTime
}


val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6)
val limit = 3000
val connector = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
val noOfRowsDeleted = sc.accumulator(0)
val table1 = sc.cassandraTable("db", "table1")

table1.filter(row => !isRecordActive(row, cal.getTime.getTime)).foreachPartition(partition => {
  val session = connector.openSession
  val listOfIds = new ArrayList[java.util.UUID]()
  val mapOfRecords = collection.mutable.Map[java.util.UUID, com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]()

  // collect limited number of records in mapOfRecords
  breakable {
    partition.foreach { elem =>
      val tb2_id = elem.get[Option[java.util.UUID]]("tb2_id").getOrElse(null)
      listOfIds.add(tb2_id)
      mapOfRecords(tb2_id) = elem
      if(listOfIds.size > limit) break
    }
  }

  // filter records found in table2 
  val select: Select = QueryBuilder.select.from("db", "table2")
  select.where(QueryBuilder.in("tb2_id", listOfIds))
  select.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)
  val resultSet = session.execute(select)
  if(!resultSet.isExhausted()){
    val resultIter = resultSet.iterator()
    while(resultIter.hasNext){
      val cur = resultIter.next
      val tb2_id = cur.getUUID("tb2_id")
      mapOfRecords.remove(tb2_id)
    }
  }

  // delete remaining records in mapOfRecords
  for ((tb2_id, tb1_record) <- mapOfRecords) {
    val delete: Delete = QueryBuilder.delete.from("db", "table1")
    delete.where(QueryBuilder.eq("tb1_id", tb1_record.get[java.util.UUID]("tb1_id")))
    delete.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)
    session.execute(delete)
    noOfRowsDeleted += 1
  }
  session.close()
})
```

Problem with this solution:

1. noOfRowsDeleted is not much, they are around 100K for a single run. And let's say I do subsequent runs one after the other, noOfRowsDeleted reduce in each iteration. The reason for this reduction is that I am referring to the first 3000 elements of partition(localized lookup) each time and trying to find them in table2, and the batch available for deletion is reducing in size.
2. If I try to increase the limit from 3000, I get a memory out exception. I suspect it is because of inner objects (listOfIds, mapOfRecords) that I am creating, although I am not sure.

The number of partitions is 2000.

I realize that I am doing something stupid and there must be some better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

**Trying to achieve: 2 Million deletions in one go as compared to the current 100K.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RDD API I recommend to use Spark SQL instead, at least to prepare the data - it's easier to work with it, compared to RDD.

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Prepare data - you just read both tables and doing filtering first table for old data, and then doing [left anti join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join) with second table, so you'll have only not matching records left
2. Do the deletion using the [deleteFromCassandra function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/5_saving.md#deleting-rows-and-columns) from the RDD API.

Something like this (not tested the actual deletion, only the data preparation, but should work):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

val df1 = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "table1", "keyspace" -> "ks"))
  .load().select("tb1_id", "tb2_id", "first_req_time")
val df2 = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "table2", "keyspace" -> "ks"))
  .load().select("tb2_id")

// Find old data (current_date - 180 days)
val df1_old = df1.filter(to_date($"first_req_time") < date_sub(current_date, 180))
// find records that aren't in the second table
val joined = df1_old.join(df2, Seq("tb2_id"), "left_anti")
  .select("tb1_id", "tb2_id")
// perform deletion
joined.rdd.deleteFromCassandra("ks", "table1", 
   keyColumns = SomeColumns("tb1_id", "tb2_id")
```